# Is this "one-bit-a-time" write pattern flash-friendly?

Tags: flash

I need to record some one-bit flag data into flash every minute (or every hour).

For this purpose, I reserved a 4-KB page in the flash (no filesystem). And write **one bit** to that page sequentially every minute. At the beginning, the whole flash is empty/erased.

Since the flash can only be read/written at a page granularity. I am not sure if the flash controller will do this when a new bit comes:

1. Read the **old** page which hold the existing data into the
   controller's cache.
2. Write the new bit into the cached page.
3. Pick a **new** erased page and write the cached page to there. (to avoid erasing the old page)

If so, I think the all the available pages will soon be consumed up. And **from then on** erase operation is inevitable for new bit, which will impact the performance.

Am I right on this? Is there a better way for such write pattern?

### ADD 1 - 7:31 AM 10/25/2020

I am using **W25Q32** flash chip from Winbond, which provides **4K pages and each page hold 256 bytes**. I can only write at the **page** granularity.

I guess the controller is integrated in the W25Q32 chip and should have the capability to automatically take the 3-step approach above for a **bit** write. Maybe there is some RAM cache in the controller. Otherwise I have to do those 3 steps myself.

Comment: You are writing one bit per minute and worry about performance?

Comment: Actually, I want to know if my understanding of the flash behavior correctly. The performance aspect can be ignored for now because I can change that to every hour.

Comment: Pages can be larger than 4k but in general your understanding should match reality as far as I know.

Comment: I'd suggest you check on how flash memory updates actually work, there is / has been a limit on how many times you can write a cell or block. In the worst case your circuitry might be wearing out fast with the described update scheme.

Comment: @Hannu Yeah, I have checked several wiki pages. I just wonder if there's any risk for this one-bit-a-time pattern. Or if there's any improvement I can do.

Comment: You need to provide more context: which *"flash"* chip (you seem to imply it's NAND);  what flash controller is involved?  BTW if you're using NAND flash be aware that it's a block device, you cannot write just one bit.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the reminding. Updated my question.

Comment: You will have to look up the datasheet for that flash, and read it, thoroughly.